# python application freeze on thread.join()

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, pyqt5, freeze

I'm writing a simple time tracking application in Python3 and PyQt5. Time is tracked in separate thread. Function that this thread is running doesn't access GUI code. On Windows10 application freezes after trying to close it. It's caused by calling `thread.join()`. I need to end the process in task manager to close it. On Linux Mint it works fine. I'm using threads from threading library. It doesn't work also with QThread's. If I comment out the `thread.join()` line it closes without a problem, but the code that's running by this thread doesn't finish.

Thread is initialized in `__init__()` function of Window class.

```
self.trackingThread = Thread(target = self.track)
```

Function that is responsible for tracking time:

```
    def track(self):
    startTime = time()
    lastWindowChangeTime = startTime
    while self.running:
        # check if active window has changed
        if self.active_window_name != get_active_window_name():
            if self.active_window_name in self.applications_time:
                self.applications_time[self.active_window_name] += int(time() - lastWindowChangeTime) // 60 # time in minutes)
            else:
                self.applications_time[self.active_window_name] = int(time() - lastWindowChangeTime) // 60  # time in minutes

            lastWindowChangeTime = time()
            self.active_window_name = get_active_window_name()


    totalTime = int(time() - startTime) // 60  # time in minutes
    if date.today() in self.daily_time:
        self.daily_time[date.today()] += totalTime
    else:
        self.daily_time[date.today()] = totalTime
```

Joining the thread:

```
   def saveAndQuit(self):
        self.running = False
        self.trackingThread.join() # the line that's causing application freeze
        self.save()
        QApplication.instance().quit()
```

EDIT:
Example:
https://pastebin.com/vt3BfKJL

relevant code:

```
def get_active_window_name():
    active_window_name = ''

    if system() == 'Linux':
        active_window_name = check_output(['xdotool', 'getactivewindow', 'getwindowname']).decode('utf-8')
    elif system() == 'Windows':
        window = GetForegroundWindow()
        active_window_name = GetWindowText(window)

    return active_window_name
```

EDIT2:
After removing those 2 lines app closes without any problem. Is there any other way of getting active window name on Windows except win32gui?:

```
window = GetForegroundWindow()
active_window_name = GetWindowText(window)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Without a working example, this will be impossible to debug. Probably the issue is in `get_active_window_name()` but it's hard to tell...

Comment: If the thread isn't declared as a `daemon` thread, the process won't exit while the thread continues running. Perhaps just don't declare it a `daemon` thread, set the flag that tells it to exit, allow the `main` thread to exit without `join`ing the worker thread, and let the worker thread finish on its own time?

Comment: @ShaxowRanger that won't work as that would cause the Qt event loop to exit which would likely leave the win32 API call in a blocked state and the thread would still never end (see my answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue occurs because `GetWindowText()` is blocking, and so your thread can never join. To understand why, we have to delve into the [win32 documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520(v=vs.85).aspx)

> **If the target window is owned by the current process, GetWindowText causes a WM_GETTEXT message to be sent to the specified window or control**. If the target window is owned by another process and has a caption, GetWindowText retrieves the window caption text. If the window does not have a caption, the return value is a null string. This behavior is by design. It allows applications to call GetWindowText without becoming unresponsive if the process that owns the target window is not responding. **However, if the target window is not responding and it belongs to the calling application, GetWindowText will cause the calling application to become unresponsive**.

You are attempting to join the thread from within a function (`saveAndQuit`) that has been called by the Qt event loop. As such, until this function returns, the Qt event loop will not process any messages. This means the call to `GetWindowText` in the other thread has sent a message to the Qt event loop which won't be processed until `saveAndQuit` finishes. However, `saveAndQuit` is waiting for the thread to finish, and so you have a deadlock!

There are several ways to solve the deadlock, probably the easiest to implement is to recursively call `join`, with a timeout, from the Qt event loop. It's somewhat "hacky", but other alternatives mean things like changing the way your thread behaves or using QThreads.

As such, I would modify your `saveAndQuit` as follows:

```
def saveAndQuit(self):
    self.running = False
    self.trackingThread.join(timeout=0.05) 
    # if thread is still alive, return control to the Qt event loop
    # and rerun this function in 50 milliseconds
    if self.trackingThread.is_alive():
        QTimer.singleShot(50, self.saveAndQuit)
        return
    # if the thread has ended, then save and quit!
    else:
        self.save()
        QApplication.instance().quit()
```

Comment: It works, but now the save function is never called.

Comment: Oh...um, try adding `event.ignore()` to `closeEvent`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and someone here on SO advised me to use something like this:

```
class MyThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # initialize your thread, use arguments in the constructor if needed

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def run(self):
        pass # Do whatever you need here

def run_qt_app():
    my_thread = MyThread()
    my_thread.start()

    qt_app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    qt_app.aboutToQuit.connect(my_thread.terminate)

    # Setup your window here

    return qt_app.exec_()
```

Works fine for me, my_thread runs as long as qt_app is up, and finishes it's work on quit.

edit: typos

Comment: Using this solution i can close the window, but the `track()` function doesn't finish, so it's working the same as with `thread.join()` commented out.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I haven't used threading for a while and got it mixed up. What I think is missing is marking the tracking thread as daemon `self.trackingThread = Thread(target=self.track, daemon=True)`. It should then be allowed to finish.

Comment: It still freezes.